# LibGDX Box2d Android crash "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr..."

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I wrote a simple test android app with pushing balls.
When I push more than 20-30 balls on my device, the app crashes with error

```
03-31 17:07:08.414 6778-6778/com.example.balls A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 6778 (bm.examle.balls)
```

On the emulator this error occurs with 5-10 balls.

I started to learn Box2D physics with LibGDX.
I read that Box2D allows to process thousands of bodies.

So, I think that I'm not understand something in using Box2D. Can anybody give me some or advice or example of programs with many interactive bodies, please?

The code of the libgdx core project:

```
public class BallGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

BallParameters ballParameters;

volatile boolean stopWorld = false;

//parameters from Android Application
public BallGame(BallParameters ballParameters){
    this.ballParameters = ballParameters;
}

World world;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
OrthographicCamera camera;

//factor to adjust the size
private final float n = 0.05f;

@Override
public void create () {
    //create camera
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*n, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*n);
    camera.position.set(new Vector3(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f*n, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f*n, 10f));
    camera.near = 1f;
    camera.far = 20f;
    camera.update();
    //create world
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -50), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    //It creates borders around the edges of the screen
    createGround();
    createLeftWall();
    createRightWall();
    createCelling();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    doPhysicsStep(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}

//physics step, (from libgdx documentation https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d#stepping-the-simulation)
private float accumulator = 0;
private float TIME_STEP = 1/60f;
private void doPhysicsStep(float deltaTime) {
    if(stopWorld) return;
    float frameTime = Math.min(deltaTime, 0.25f);
    accumulator += frameTime;
    while (accumulator >= TIME_STEP) {
        world.step(TIME_STEP, 6, 2);
        accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
    }
}

//creates a ball and applies linear impulse with parameters from android application
//blocks stepping the world during creating ball
//calls from android application
public void pushBall(){
    stopWorld = true;
    Body ball = createBall(40*n, 40*n);
    int velocity = ballParameters.getVelocity();
    int angleDeg = ballParameters.getAngle();
    int vx = (int) (velocity*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleDeg)));
    int vy = (int) (velocity*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleDeg)));
    ball.applyLinearImpulse(vx, vy, ball.getPosition().x, ball.getPosition().y, true);
    stopWorld = false;
}

//creates a ball in a fixed place
private Body createBall(float x, float y){
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(x, y);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(50*n);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = 0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 1f;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    circle.dispose();
    return body;
}
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are having a memory problem. As it happens when pushing ball you should look at the pushBall method first to investigate. I suspect `volatile boolean stopWorld`.

Don't know where you call pushBall method but, you should check **stopWorld** before setting it to true, if you want to be sure **stopWorld** is not modified until code block is processed by another call to pushBall:

```
public void pushBall() {
    if(stopWorld) {
        return;
    }

    stopWorld = true;
    Body ball = createBall(40*n, 40*n);
    int velocity = ballParameters.getVelocity();
    int angleDeg = ballParameters.getAngle();
    int vx = (int) (velocity*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleDeg)));
    int vy = (int) (velocity*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleDeg)));
    ball.applyLinearImpulse(vx, vy, ball.getPosition().x, ball.getPosition().y, true);
    stopWorld = false;
}
```

If this doesn't help with the issue try with removing volatile from stopWorld field  definition.

`volatile boolean stopWorld` to `boolean stopWorld`

Comment: You are right. The problem appears during pushing new ball. The error is associated with the synchronization of the world object. I have edited the code like [this](http://pastebin.com/PSNpbmk9). Thank you very much!